# syntax error, unexpected kENSURE

Tags: haml

I have a problem in solving this.

```
= link_to "Bounced", bounced_email_path(@email)

  Bounces

  %span 

    = @email.bounces_count
```

I want the `Bounces`, span and other lines within the link tag.

The above code ends up in an error:

> syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting $end".

Answer (score 1):

To use the block form of [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you must remove the `body` parameter (`"Bounced"`) and use the `do` keyword to start the block:

```
= link_to bounced_email_path(@email) do
  Bounces
  %span 
    = @email.bounces_count
```